# Excessive arp requests from all routers

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, dns

My home network consists of mostly linux clients, two to three windows clients, some android devices, six routers and five raspberries running servers: dhcp, bind, nfs-kernel-server, samba and the likes.

It's a few days now the network can be very slow for some time, then it's back to normal, then slow again. I installed wireshark to find out the reason, but I'm new to this and still trying to find my way, reading howtos and so on.
Right now I'm capturing traffic, and the first thing that catches my eye is a LOT of arp requests. Maybe not a "flood", since it's just about 230.000 in 20? minutes, but multiple requests from the same IP about the same IP.

As it seems, about every router/raspberry in the net is asking the same thing over and over again. Surely by now they should be up to date?
So, in short:

- router or raspberry are asking about multiple IPs
- there ARE answers to who has this IP
- same thing going on with next device or next IP.

As I said, I run a simple local DNS-server on a raspberry, along with a DHCP-server, and I changed a couple addresses about three days ago. Since all of the asking devices are constantly running, surely they should have updated their arp-tables by now, shouldn't they?

At the moment I'm trying to find out how to filter for just requests for one IP, to see if the device stops asking after/if getting an answer, but as I said: I'm new to this, as in: installed it said 20 minutes ago and still reading the wiki...

Any help more than welcome. (I'm pretty sure I have no loop in my network cables, and I do not even succeed in telling my wlan clients to bind to one specific router, so I rather doubt I have devices connecting to two routers at once, as I read in another question...)

Thank you.

Comment: 6 routers ?  Routing loop ?

Comment: you did say you are getting replies.  ARP timeouts fairly quickly on windows (2 minutes down to 15 seconds)  - ARP is only within the LAN - and so should not cross router boundaries - Its unlikely to be overloaded due to ARP - UNLESS something else is wrong such as a loop or a poor connection

Comment: Are those normal ARP packets? Or Gratuitous ARP also present?

Comment: Do you use the routers as real routers, or switches? How is the network laid out, what are the segments (include a diagram, if possible)? Does it only happen in one segment? As always with debugging problems: Try to narrow down the error source, by making the setup simpler, and doing "tests" of some sort that will help you decide what and what cannot be the reason, and where the problem comes from. Without any concrete information, we can only do wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm OP. Seems one of the routers is broken - besides suddenly sending IPv6-packets while not even configured or allowed to do this, I took it out. Net is back to old speed now. I hope it stays like that.

Thanks anyway.